# ASP.NET C# gridview edit sets focus to next cell but does nto select current value

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I have been searching but cannot find an answer.  I have a gridview that allows the user to enter hours for each day.  When the user enters the hours the program calculates and updates the total hours cell then sets focus to the next days cell.  The problem is if there is a value in that cell it is not selected.  So if the user does not delete the number (i.e. 0 ) and puts in a value - for example a 2 they see 20.  I am trying to get the value - 0 in this example - highlighted so typing overwrites this value.
here is a snippet of my case selection :

```
     Switch (CurrentCellNumber)
      {
         case 2:
          {
            row.FindControl("SaturdayHours").Focus();
            break;
           }
```

I hope this makes sense.
Thanks in advance.  If this was answered somewhere else I apologize - I could not find it and the link would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no need for you to perform this task on the server side. This is a job for your client side. You can use either pure javascript or JQuery, here is a quick sample of how it can be used:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    //jquery selectors can be more specific to match only inputs in your Grid.
    $("input:text").focus(function() { $(this).select(); } );
});
```

The code above will select the content on focus causing that anything that is typed later on the input text will be overridden.